# IE11 font rendering ignoring margins on container blocks

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-11

I am currently modifying a site for IE11 compatibility and there is a major bug being caused by the CSS font-faces loading.

I am skinning on top of a theme, and am overriding the original theme's font-family for the body of the site. However, what is happening is the site loads with a default font family, the theme's font family is loaded and finally my skin's font family is applied.

What seems to be happening is that on load, the margins for the unstyled text are being set, then as the additional font styles are loaded, the margins remain the same, resulting in overlapping blocks. The blocks correct themselves when moused over, but this is far from ideal.

See the links below as an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8N5r.jpg
After the page has loaded, divs overlap.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsXn3.jpg
Once the element has been moused-over (This is the way the content should display on load).

Is there a way to make IE11 position divs properly depending on the size of the content?

Comment: please add relevant css and html and a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: In fact, please first create a [minimum verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then put that online using jsbin or jsfiddle, or the newer [thimble](https://thimble.mozilla.org)